# Pushing a docker image to aws ecr gives no basic auth credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, devops, amazon-ecr, docker-push

when I try to push a docker image to aws ecr it fails giving the following

```
sudo docker push xxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/my-app:1.0

7d9a9c94af8d: Preparing 
f77d412f54b5: Preparing 
629960860aca: Preparing 
f019278bad8b: Preparing 
8ca4f4055a70: Preparing 
3e207b409db3: Waiting 
no basic auth credentials
```

although logging in is done successfully

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-2 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin xxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com

Login Succeeded
```

And the /home/[my user]/.docker/config.json file has the following data

```
{
    "auths": {
        "xxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com": {
            "auth": "QVsVkhaRT...."
        }
    }
}
```

I am using aws cli version 2.3.5

```
aws --version
aws-cli/2.3.5 Python/3.8.8 Linux/5.8.0-63-generic exe/x86_64.ubuntu.20 prompt/off
```

I am using docker version 20.10.10

```
docker --version 
Docker version 20.10.10, build b485636
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running `sudo docker push`.

This means that the credentials in your account won't be used. Instead, Docker is trying to use (nonexistent) credentials in the root user account.

Changing your command to `docker push` should suffice.